# Monitor network traffic with just a simple router

Tags: monitoring

I'd like to monitor incoming and outgoing network traffic from my PC (windows 7). My network setup is as follows: `internet -> 8 port Cnet LAN router -> (PC's && Wireless Router). Is it possible for me to monitor and block visited websites on this network? Are the tools free? What are they?

I'd especially like to know if there is anyone on the network streaming music or video.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most consumer routers cannot do application or port level traffic monitoring so most likely no.  Checking the documentation of the LAN/Router would be the place to look to confirm this.

Untangle is a free product that can do this however it must be installed on a dedicated PC w/ 2 NIC's.
Traffic can also be monitored and controlled w/ a firewall device, look at Sonicwall, Watchguard, Fortinet, etc.
If you just need to monitor overall traffic levels then PRTG can do it if the router supports SNMP. This will not provide info on specific traffic types, ports nor will it block anything.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to monitor on the "8 port Cnet LAN router" or on the "PCs && Wireless Router"? In the first case, you're probably out of luck because that thing is unlikely to have any brains. In the second case, you may be able to install [OpenWRT](http://openwrt.org/) or [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/) on the wireless router and monitor from there. There's numerous ways to monitor traffic once you have an alternate Linux-based firmware in place, but whether you can do that will depend on the brand and model of that device.